# Mathematica equivalent of Pandas groupby and sum

Tags: pandas-groupby, wolfram-mathematica

I imported a World Health Organization (WHO) csv file with Covid-19 cases per country from January 2020 into Mathematica. The file is a table with "Date Reported", "Country Code", "Country Name", "WHO Region", "New Cases", "Cumulative Cases", "New Deaths", "Cumulative Deaths" as columns ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dig4K.png)).

I want to group the countries by the same "WHO Region" and sum the "New Cases", "Cumulative Cases", "New Deaths" and "Cumulative Deaths" that have the same "Date Reported" (for example sum all the cumulative cases in Europe in each day). I can easily do that in Python using the Pandas library with the functions groupby() and sum(), like in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
worldCases = pd.read_csv("WHO-COVID-19-global-data_02April2022.csv",usecols=[0,2,3,4,5,6,7])
regionCases = worldCases.groupby(['WHO_region','Date_reported']).sum()
```

How could I achieve the same goal in Mathematica?

The csv file can be downloaded from here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/80ytphej636239x/WHO-COVID-19-global-data_02April2022.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Tabulating for each date with a basic method first

```
data = Import[
   "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/80ytphej636239x/WHO-COVID-19-global-data_02April2022.csv"];

regions = Union[Rest[data[[All, 4]]]];

splitout = Cases[data, {_, _, _, #, __}] & /@ regions;

dates = Union[Rest[data[[All, 1]]]];

eachdate[onedate_] := Module[{},
  splitout = Cases[data,
     {onedate, _, _, #, __}] & /@ regions;

  countup[onesplit_] := Module[{totals},
    totals = Total[onesplit[[All, {5, 6, 7, 8}]]];
    NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3] & /@ totals];

  Labeled[
   TableForm[countup /@ splitout, TableAlignments -> Right,
    TableHeadings -> {regions, data[[1, {5, 6, 7, 8}]]}],
   onedate, {{Top, Left}}]]

(* Just the last three dates *)
eachdate /@ Take[dates, -3]
```

*-tables not shown-*

Plotting over the dates

```
eachdate[onedate_] := Module[{},
  splitout = Cases[data,
     {onedate, _, _, #, __}] & /@ regions;
  totals = Total[#[[All, {5, 6, 7, 8}]]] & /@ splitout;
  MapAt[{onedate, #} &, totals, {All, All}]]

set = eachdate /@ dates;

newCases = set[[All, All, 1]];
cumulativeCases = set[[All, All, 2]];
newDeaths = set[[All, All, 3]];
cumulativeDeaths = set[[All, All, 4]];

DateListPlot[Transpose[newCases],
 PlotLegends -> regions, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabel -> data[[1, 5]]]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[cumulativeCases],
 PlotLegends -> regions, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabel -> data[[1, 6]]]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[newDeaths],
 PlotLegends -> regions, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabel -> data[[1, 7]]]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[cumulativeDeaths],
 PlotLegends -> regions, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabel -> data[[1, 8]]]
```

[image]

***Equivalent tabulation procedure using a Dataset***

```
headers = First[data];

dataset = Dataset[Association[
      Thread[headers -> #]] & /@ Rest[data]];

cols = Take[headers, -4];

datatable = dataset[
   GroupBy["WHO_region"], GroupBy["Date_reported"],
   Total, cols];

sampledate = Last[dates];

Labeled[TableForm[Outer[
    datatable[#1][sampledate][#2] &, regions, cols] /. 
   x_Integer :> NumberForm[x, DigitBlock -> 3],
  TableAlignments -> Right, TableHeadings -> {regions, cols}],
 sampledate, {{Top, Left}}]
```

> ```
> 2022-03-30
>          New_cases  Cumulative_cases  New_deaths  Cumulative_deaths
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
>  AFRO        2,812         8,580,381          24            171,086
>  AMRO      105,798       150,709,372       1,785          2,700,130
>  EMRO        3,789        21,576,432          62            340,628
>  EURO      718,203       202,693,049       1,450          1,940,630
> Other            0               764           0                 13
> SEARO       33,699        57,130,457         220            778,986
>  WPRO      527,512        46,071,142         826            211,262
> ```

And a sample chart

```
DateListPlot[Map[Function[region,
   {#, datatable[region][#][cols[[1]]]} & /@ dates], regions],
 PlotLegends -> regions, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> cols[[1]]]
```

[image]